# hadoop top10 treemap didn`t ouput any data

Tags: java, hadoop, treemap

I have Java code that should map a top10 treemap with `hadoop`. When I run the code however I do not get any data output. Where am I missing something?

Code:

```
public class Mapper1_1 extends Mapper<Object, Text, NullWritable, Text> {

 public static final int limit = 10;
 private TreeMap<Integer, Text> top10cats = new TreeMap<Integer, Text>();
 private int flag=0;
 private int tmp=0;

@Override
protected void map(Object key, Text value,
        Mapper<Object, Text, NullWritable, Text>.Context context)
        throws IOException, InterruptedException {
    String line=value.toString();
    if(!line.isEmpty()){
    String[] words=line.split("\t");
    if(flag!=5){
         System.out.println(words[0]+"&&&&&&&&&&&&"+words[1]);
         flag++;
    }
    top10cats.put(Integer.parseInt(words[1]), value);
    if(top10cats.size()>limit){
        tmp++;
        top10cats.remove(top10cats.firstKey());
    }
    }
}

@Override
protected void cleanup(
        Mapper<Object, Text, NullWritable, Text>.Context context)
        throws IOException, InterruptedException {
    System.out.println("&&&&&&&"+tmp);
     for(Text text: top10cats.values()){
         System.out.println("##########"+text.toString());
         context.write(NullWritable.get(), text);
        }
}
}


public class Reducer1_1 extends Reducer<NullWritable, Text, NullWritable, Text> {

public static final int N = 10;
private TreeMap<Integer, Text> top10cats = new TreeMap<Integer, Text>();

@Override
protected void reduce(NullWritable key, Iterable<Text> values,
        Reducer<NullWritable, Text, NullWritable, Text>.Context context)
        throws IOException, InterruptedException {
    for (Text val : values) {
             String tokens[] = val.toString().split("\t");
             Integer weight = Integer.parseInt(tokens[1]);
             top10cats.put(weight, val);
             if (top10cats.size() > N)
                 top10cats.remove(top10cats.firstKey());
         }
    for(Text text:top10cats.values()){
        context.write(NullWritable.get(), text);
    }
}
}
```

The resulting output when running the program:

```
2018-07-10 09:16:19,220 INFO [org.apache.hadoop.mapred.MapTask] -
   mapreduce.task.io.sort.mb: 100 2018-07-10 09:16:19,220 INFO
   [org.apache.hadoop.mapred.MapTask] - soft limit at 83886080
   2018-07-10 09:16:19,220 INFO [org.apache.hadoop.mapred.MapTask] -
   bufstart = 0; bufvoid = 104857600 2018-07-10 09:16:19,220 INFO
   [org.apache.hadoop.mapred.MapTask] - kvstart = 26214396; length =
   6553600 2018-07-10 09:16:19,226 INFO
   [org.apache.hadoop.mapred.MapTask] - Map output collector class =
   org.apache.hadoop.mapred.MapTask$MapOutputBuffer
   1000473355&&&&&&&&&&&&39 
   1000473355   39 
   1001103582&&&&&&&&&&&&6
   1001103582   6 
   1001698581&&&&&&&&&&&&2 
   1001698581   2
   1004307115&&&&&&&&&&&&24 
   1004307115   24 
   1005179492&&&&&&&&&&&&2
   1005179492   2 
   &&&&&&&1605
   ##########
   ##########
   ##########
   ##########
   ##########
   ##########
   ##########
   ##########
   ##########
   ##########
```

2018-07-10 09:16:19,287 INFO [org.apache.hadoop.mapred.LocalJobRunner] -  2018-07-10 09:16:19,287
       INFO [org.apache.hadoop.mapred.MapTask] - Starting flush of map
       output 2018-07-10 09:16:19,288 INFO
       [org.apache.hadoop.mapred.MapTask] - Spilling map output 2018-07-10
       09:16:19,288 INFO [org.apache.hadoop.mapred.MapTask] - bufstart = 0;
       bufend = 10; bufvoid = 104857600 2018-07-10 09:16:19,291 INFO
       [org.apache.hadoop.mapred.MapTask] - kvstart = 26214396(104857584);
       kvend = 26214360(104857440); length = 37/6553600 2018-07-10
       09:16:19,307 INFO [org.apache.hadoop.mapred.MapTask] - Starting flush
       of map output 2018-07-10 09:16:19,307 INFO
       [org.apache.hadoop.mapred.MapTask] - (RESET) equator 0 kv
       26214396(104857584) kvi 26214356(104857424) 2018-07-10 09:16:19,307
       INFO [org.apache.hadoop.mapred.MapTask] - Spilling map output
       2018-07-10 09:16:19,307 INFO [org.apache.hadoop.mapred.MapTask] -
       bufstart = 0; bufend = 10; bufvoid = 104857600 2018-07-10
       09:16:19,727 INFO [org.apache.hadoop.mapred.MapTask] - kvstart =
       26214396(104857584); kvend = 26214360(104857440); length = 37/6553600
       2018-07-10 09:16:19,744 INFO [org.apache.hadoop.mapred.MapTask] -
       Ignoring exception during close for
       org.apache.hadoop.mapred.MapTask$NewOutputCollector@61ccfc89
       java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException: 1  at
       com.zy.top10.Reducer1_1.reduce(Reducer1_1.java:21)   at
       com.zy.top10.Reducer1_1.reduce(Reducer1_1.java:1)

- problem： System.out.println("##########"+text.toString()); The
  text.toString() is null.Why?

Comment: Data Format：1000473355 \t 39 \n
1001103582 \t 6 \n
1001698581 \t 2 \n

Comment: I have 1619 tested data.The "top10cats.remove(top10cats.firstKey());"just run 1605 time (you can see 'tmp' output).Why?

Comment: Please help me .Nobody knows? Wow.